# Why does OpenGL lighten my scene when multisampling with an FBO?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, multisampling

I just switched my OpenGL drawing code from drawing to the display directly to using an off-screen FBO with render buffers attached.  The off-screen FBO is blitted to the screen correctly when I allocate normal render buffer storage.

However, when I enable multisampling on the render buffers (via `glRenderbufferStorageMultisample`), every color in the scene seems like it has been brightened (thus giving different colors than the non-multisampled part).

I suspect there's some `glEnable` option that I need to set to maintain the same colors, but I can't seem to find any mention of this problem elsewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide snapshots of the problem and the expected correct result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same problem, due to the lack of proper downsampling because of mismatching sample locations. What worked for me was:

- A separate "single sample" FBO with identical attachments, format and dimension (with texture or renderbuffer attached) to blit into for downsampling and then draw/blit this to the window buffer
- Render into a multisample window buffer with multisample texture having the same sample count as input, by passing all corresponding samples per fragment using a GLSL fragment shader. This worked with sample shading enabled and is the overkill approach for deferred shading as you can calculate light, shadow, AO, etc. per sample.
- I did also rather sloppy manual downsampling to single sample framebuffers using GLSL, where I had to fetch each sample separately using `texelFetch()`.

Things got really slow with multisampling. Although CSAA performed better than MSAA, I recommend to take a look at FXAA shaders for postprocessing as a considerable alternative, when performance is an issue or those rather new extensions required, such as **ARB_texture_multisample**, are not available.

Accessing samples in GLSL:

```
vec4 texelDownsampleAvg(sampler2DMS sampler,ivec2 texelCoord,const int sampleCount)
{
    vec4 accum = texelFetch(sampler,texelCoord,0);
    for(int sample = 1; sample < sampleCount; ++sample) {
        accum += texelFetch(sampler,texelCoord,sample);
    }
    return accum / sampleCount;
}
```

- http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample.txt
- http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit.txt

11) Should blits be allowed between buffers of different bit sizes?

```
Resolved: Yes, for color buffers only.  Attempting to blit
between depth or stencil buffers of different size generates
INVALID_OPERATION.
```

13) How should BlitFramebuffer color space conversion be
    specified?  Do we allow context clamp state to affect the
    blit?

```
Resolved: Blitting to a fixed point buffer always clamps,
blitting to a floating point buffer never clamps.  The context
state is ignored.
```

- http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sample_shading.txt
- [Blitting multisampled FBO with multiple color attachments in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1773973/1175253)

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was changing the renderbuffer color format.  I picked `GL_RGBA32F` and `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F` (figuring that I wanted the highest precision), and the NVIDIA drivers interpret that differently (I suspect sRGB compensation, but I could be wrong).

The renderbuffer image formats I found to work are `GL_RGBA8` with `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24`.

Comment: Sounds, as if this format is equal to your window's pixel format, where color format conversion could be the cause as you stated. I've got an RGB16F into an RGB8 using that GLSL snippet, where conversion could be implied. Even so, I can't see the cause in sRGB yet, since this must either be a driver optimization bug, because sRGB has dedicated extensions.

Comment: That was the part I wasn't understanding, then. Your solution solves the problem more generally than what I needed, but it's the more correct answer.

Comment: I don't claim my answer is correct, as long as I don't know the exact reason myself. Downsampling using GLSL is rather an inefficient workaround than anything I could regard as 'state of the art'.

Comment: Another thought is, what happens with your alpha values? Is there any blend or alpha tests/functions active? What happens, if you render into an multisampled RGB32F or disable those tests? I'll try it out as soon as possible.